# First React application setup: Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to setup my first react application. I installed all the npm packages required. But getting this error.

Comment: It's difficult to help you with the information currently in your question. Could you perhaps include your webpack config?

Comment: Definitely gonna need more info. Though I do remember that I got this error when I was using a Webpack 3 schema with the Webpack 4 module. My error was I was using `loaders` in the `module` configuration, whereas with 4 you have to use `rules` instead. So to start check your versions and if you're building with Webpack 4, make sure you're using a Webpack 4 schema.

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall webpack --save-dev

npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev